# How to prevent an image being downloaded on mobile?

Tags: html, image, srcset

Assuming this markup:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="//placehold.it/350x150&text=Up+to+767" />
    <source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="//placehold.it/350x150&text=Up+to+991" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/570x200&text=Desktop+image" class="responsive-image" />
</picture>
```

Is it possible to prevent the 'up to 767' image from being downloaded on small devices, without using JavaScript? Whilst the following CSS will *hide* the image, and appear to have solved the problem visually:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .responsive-image { display: none; }
}
```

It will still download the image, which is what I want to avoid. I was hoping I could simply provide an empty `srcset` attribute for the image I want hidden, but then the next image gets loaded instead.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n68ousqu/

Comment: Detect a "small device" and script avoid it to be invoked.

Comment: I'm leaning towards doing that as it seems like the only option... thanks for the comment.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution Chris?

Comment: It seems that, in Chrome at least, you can take the HTML and CSS from my original post and simply add loading="lazy" to the img element to get this working.

Comment: Then, the second line of HTML can be removed.